# ODBC connections setup to import source ininformaitca

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to import oracle table into sources (designer informatica) and when i try to import its giving me error [Microsoft][ODBC driver for oracle][oracle] ORA-121154:TNS: couldn't resolve the connect identifier specified
Am unable to figure out hoe to install odbc drivers if they are missing.
 Please help
k

Answer (score 0):

Do you have oracle client installed in your machine? If so oracle wire protocol will be available. Try connect using that

Make sure you have tns entry available under $ORACLE_HOME/client_1/network/admin